# Can I convert this if else statements into pattern matching without nested pattern matching in scala?

Tags: scala, if-statement, switch-statement, pattern-matching

Say I have this conditions having all the values depending on each other -

```
val a = 9
val b = 89
val c = 0

val result =
  if (a == 0) 0
  else if (b == 4) 0
  else if (c < 90) 0
  else a + b + c
```

How to code this using pattern matching without nesting it or is it okay to code in this way. Is there some disadvantage of using if else condition in this situation instead of using pattern matching.

Comment: `if (a == 0 || b == 4 || c < 90) 0 else a+b+c`

Comment: the condition given was just an example @jwvh, the dependency may be actually huge(say instead of 3 variables(a,b,c) there may be 20 (a,b,c,d,e,....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can do this:

```
val a = 9
val b = 89
val c = 0

val result =
  (a, b, c) match {
    case (0, _, _)             => 0
    case (_, 0, _)             => 0
    case (_, _, c) if (c < 90) => 0
    case (a, b, c)             => a + b + c
  }
```

But being honest, I would just use `if / else`.
Here you are not **matching** against any **pattern**.

Answer (score 2):

You can also ignore match argument:

```scala
val a = 9
val b = 89
val c = 0

val result = a match {
  case _ if a == 0 => 0
  case _ if b == 0 => 0 
  case _ if c < 90 => 0
  case _           => a + b + c
}
```

This isn't better than `if/else` statements, but still it is next way of doing that.